# Broken links Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a large pages library in SharePoint on line which supports an internal information portal.
Is there any way we can scan for broken links using Power Automate so that the owner can regularly be alerted to invalid urls? If not does anyone know an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to check for invalid URL. Can you please elaborate the scenario so that I can suggest some alternatives.

Comment: One scenario is that the pages are edited by multiple users - sometimes they are linking to other pages or documents which are correct at the time of publishing. Subsequently the target items may have been moved or deleted (the author is unaware) and so the user gets the 'link has been removed' message etc. So what we need is some kind of solution that the owner can check where these instances may be occurring so that they can then update the links.

Comment: Hmm, if the links are outside of SharePoint there is no option to check the validity of the url